# How to insert text content in most secure way from textarea in MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am simply inserting the text that you write in the textarea in mySQL without using any extra method to protect my site... Actually i just made a test wrote the html code that creates a input textbox to the textarea and saved it into mysql, which prints me the component on the page...

How can i make it write secure content on textarea that does not allow you to write html tags or smth, I just wanna increase the security of my site.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `$textarea` contains your textarea value,you can do `$db_value = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($textarea)))` and insert `$db_value` to the database.

`strip_tags` strips the text of html tags and mysql_real_escape_string encodes special characters and makes it safe to insert into a database...

for mysql_real_escape_string: check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

for strip_tags check: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 2):

Try to use *Prepared Statements*
http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

And remove all unwanted chars from the given text and finally use **mysql_real_escape_string**
to escape the string for MySQL.